# PHP, preg_match, select part of many div tags

Tags: php, html-parsing, pcre

so i need to take the whole div with class "1" but it stops at the div class "1.1" ending  so i want to get from this:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="1">
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
        <div class="1.1">
            trolololol
        </div>
        <div class="1.2">
            trolo2lolo
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

only this:

```
<div class="1">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <div class="1.1">
        trolololol
    </div>
    <div class="1.2">
        trolo2lolo
    </div>
</div>
```

but for now i get only:

```
<div class="1">
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <div class="1.1">
        trolololol
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Regexp are not that intelligent to count how many tags you have opened and need to be closed before stopping the match. It stops at the first occurence of `</div>`. Try to use a real html parser if you want to access tags as real tags and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions should not be used to parse documents like XML, HTML, "BBCode", JSON...
You should look for a real DOM parser, for example [PHP's DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)